# How to valid input to matches data in CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv, validation, user-input, verify

I'm using Ruby 2.7 above. I've been working this task and still learning. I'm pretty sure that I am not using the right code. This task require me to do a mimic atm program. One of the requirements is where I need to check user valid inputs are matches the data in the CSV.file before user can access the program.

**I'm using ruby (not allowed to use rails or any advance ruby code)**. I searched for similar program anywhere for reference but mostly does not involve with CSV file. How do I check that input from user is valid and matches in CSV file? I'm having trouble on how to do a validation and how to valid with two inputs (username and password). This program is run on command-line. Apologies if im not being clear enough. Can you tell me from my code where I'm going wrong please?

I have three .rb files and two csv files. I am not sure if I'm supposed to create two separate csv files.

- function.rb (where all the functions)
- login.rb (verify username and password from 'user.csv' file before proceed to system.rb file)
- system.rb (the main where all data save or changes in 'account.csv' file)

below is `function.rb` file.

```
require 'csv'

class Function   

  def log_in(user)
    CSV.foreach('user.csv', 'r', headers => true) do |row|
     #check the user is valid, else error
      if row[0] == uname && row[1] == pwd
        puts "succesfully login"
        ATMSystem.main_menu  
      end
    end

    if login == false
      puts "invalid credentials."
      Login.log_menu
    end   
 end
```

`login.rb` file

```
require './function'

class Inn

  def signin
    function = AtmFunction.new

    puts "Account login"
    puts "Enter username"
    uname = gets.chomp
    puts "Enter password"
    pwd = gets.chomp
    user = [uname, pwd]

    function.log_in(user)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say this is your `users.csv` file:

```
name,password
bob,1234
alice,5678
```

This is one possible option.

Load the file into an array of hashes [Enumerable#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-to_h) and [Hash#transform_keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys):

```
require 'csv'

data_file = 'user.csv'
user_map = CSV.foreach(data_file, headers: true).map do |row|
  row.to_h.transform_keys(&:to_sym)
end

user_map
#=> [{:name=>"bob", :password=>"1234"}, {:name=>"alice", :password=>"5678"}]
```

Then, given the input from the user:

```
input_username = 'bob'
input_password = '1234'
```

Check if user exists and in case compare the password:

```
user = user_map.find { |h| h[:name] == input_username }
#=> {:name=>"bob", :password=>"1234"}
user[:password] == input_password
#=> true
```

Check the password if [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) returns a non `nil` value: the user doesn't exist:

```
input_username = 'ron'
user = user_map.find { |h| h[:name] == input_username }
user
#=> nil
```

---

Following your implementation you can also write:

```
login_passed = false
CSV.foreach(data_file, headers: true) do |row|
  login_passed = row['name'] == input_username && row['password'] == input_password
  break if login_passed
end

login_passed
#=> true (or false)
```

Comment: Hi @iGian Sorry but is there a way without using `.map` that relate to array? I am still not very familiar with such method. still new here. I've try to implementing this into my code but it isn't working.

Comment: @Jgrace, please check the edit. I encourage you to dig into https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html etc. in Docs. You can also find plenty of very good examples on SO.

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers! They've been really useful. I made some changes into my code. I used `.find` instead of `.map` as i'm more familiar to it but your explanation was great.

Comment: Glad for it. `map` in the last example was a typo. Updated. `foreach` is already a loop.

Comment: alright no worry. thanks for the info's!  appreciated it.